# Class loader Jboss (first Web-Inf classes)

Tags: java, class, jboss

I want to deploy an EAR, and the WAR contains override classes from a lib jar. Example:

I have a pom.xml including a `example.jar` that contains a `com.example.ClassExample` but in my WAR project I've overrided this class inside the classpath:
`com.example.ClassExample`.

It's a Spring Boot app, so when I run in a Tomcat embbeded server, the first class to load is the ClassExample class into the classpath (that's great).

But in a Jboss EAP 6.1 loads first the ClassExample from example.jar. I can't remove example.jar because I need other classes from this library.

Any help? Thanks